# Change keyboard shortcut for command for all users

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I have a requirement to change the keyboard shortcut in Xfce that runs the command `xflock4`. I understand how Xfce controls the keyboard shortcut on a *per-user* basis, but can not find any mechanism for doing this on a *global* basis for all existing and new users.

How do you change an Xfce command's keyboard shortcut for all users on a system?

Comment: Interesting precision (I think): all users on a system, you mean "all existing", or "all existing and coming"? Because this can influence answers (and eventually rule out the script ones, doing the same change for all user accounts)

Comment: I need this setting to be for all existing and future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XFCE, the [default theme](http://www.xfce.org/documentation/4.2/manuals/xfwm4) is in `$(datadir)/themes/Default/xfwm4/keythemerc`.  $datadir is often defined to be `/usr/share/`.  If it is for you, you should be able to edit the default configuration file manually, which everyone would then inherit.

Comment: `keythemerc` seems to have the keyboard shortcuts for all the commands that are built into the window manager, but none of the keyboard shortcuts used to launch other applications like xflock4 or xfquit4 are defined there. I'm looking to change those shortcuts.